# nhibernate does not query database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a VS 2012 solution with Nhibernate running. I have a sessionmanager, and mapping files, and a simple respority with the following method.

```
 public User GetUser()    
    {
        ISession session = SessionManager.OpenSession();
        User user = session.Query<User>().First();

        return user;
    }
```

However...if I call the method, no results are returned from the query (while there is data in the DB)...my mapping files etc are deployed to the bin folder.

The mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Main.Objects.User,Main.Objects">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="UserName"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;Database=DB;uid=root;pwd=root</property>
    <mapping assembly="Main.Objects"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

basic user class:

```
 public class SYUser
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string UserName  { get; set; }
    }
```

The mapping and hibernate config file is in a database specific class library, the query is in another one and objects in another one as well...so 3 class libraries

Any ideas?

Comment: Beside the fact that you should use the `using` construct, you need to provide more details. There are lots of things that can be wrong.

Comment: Edited with more info

Comment: Maybe you could add `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` to the `session-factory` section to see what query is being issued, if any?

Comment: `First()` should throw an exception of there are no results.  Is that the actual `GetUser()` method you are using?  It's suspicious to me because it looks like the method just says "give me a user, any user" which doesn't sound useful to me.

Comment: My two best "shot in the dark" guesses: 1. check your connection string and make sure you're pointing at the right database.  2. make sure you're not swallowing an exception somewhere.  Good luck!

Comment: This query is not usefull no, but thats because I'm just trying to test if the DB connection works. Its not meant as an actual method I would be using. I'll do some more research today with the suggestions given

Comment: Well I found one of the problems, I forgot the .hbm in the mapping file extension. However now I get the classic 'Could not compile mapping document' + 'Could not find dialect in config' error

Comment: Well I got the retrieving of data working, I changed serveral things, one of the things was the casing of the dialiect (MySQL instead ofMySql). It is really slow though...have to look into that later :) Atleast everything is working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got the retrieving of data working, I changed several things, one of the things was the casing of the dialect (MySQL instead ofMySql). It is really slow though...have to look into that later :) At least everything is working now :)

- forgot the .hbm in the mapping file extension as well

Comment: Yes, .hbm as embedded resource is the problem!